# Need ideas how to build push notifications service C#

Tags: c#, android, sql, service, notifications

I need help in building push notification service on windows server, to send notifications to android phones.

By now I can send notifications but I need some automatic kind of thing that will handle huge numbers of send requests.

At the moment each Registration ID of device, that installed application, sent to the App Server that stores it in SQL Table. DB itself has table that creates all push notification content for each Registration IDs.

The main goal is to create Service, that will run on the App Server where Database exists, its purpose will be to listen to DB notification table and send them instantly to the client device. The problem is to handle thousands of notifications to be sent as fast as possible.

Do anyone have any ideas how to implement it in the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Windows Azure Notification Hubs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj927170.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can look into [Mqtt](http://mqtt.org/documentation).

you can also see how to use mqtt with c# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635440/c-sharp-client-library-for-subscribing-publishing-mqtt-really-small-message-bro)

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple technology for the same.
Latest is SignalR

However you can try your hands on https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp as well

Thanks
Nipun

Comment: It seems that [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/923) will no support Apple's latest changes so won't work in near future.